# fadeOut won't animate properly in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, firefox, fadeout

here's my plugin i am trying to develop:

http://jsfiddle.net/9FcN3/3/

problem is:

second fade out wont work in Firefox, cant figure out why. in all other browsers this works like a charm, and in Firefox first fadeOut animates but second fadeOut wont animate (simply removes object).

HTML:

```
<div id="holder">

        <div id="thmb"></div>
        <div id="logo"></div>
        <div id="player">
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ytplayer.js"  charset="utf-8"></script>

</div>
```

JS:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    //Hide vid if browser is IE or Safari
    var isMSIE = /*@cc_on!@*/0;
    if (isMSIE) {
        $('#player').css('display','none');
    }
    if (navigator.userAgent.match(/AppleWebKit/)) {
        $('#player').css('display','none');
    }

  // Plugin lounch
    $('#thmb').click(function(){
        $(this).fadeOut('slow', timeout());
    });

    function timeout(){
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('#logo').fadeOut('slow',play);
        },2000);
    }

    function play() {
      if (player) {

        //show vid if browser is IE or Safari
        if (isMSIE) {
            $('#player').css('display','block');
        } 
        if (navigator.userAgent.match(/AppleWebKit/)) {
            $('#player').css('display','block');
        }

        player.playVideo();

      }
    }

});
```

Comment: unfortunately.this is bug from mozilla..try another approach https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=708814

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to replace $(this).fadeOut('slow', timeout()); with $(this).fadeOut('slow', timeout);